# Extract Names from List using If Then Statements

Tags: r, list

Given the list below, I would like to extract the names of each sublist which has values greater than 3.

```
a <- c(1, 2, 3) 
b <- c(4, 5, 6) 
c <- c(7, 8, 9) 
list.x <- list(a,b,c)
names(list.x) <- c('Foo', 'Foobar', 'Foobarred')
```

Expected output

```
[1] "Foobar" "Foobarred"
```

I have toyed around with lapply, but I cannot understand how to loop through the values and return the sublist names, rather than the values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did it in steps.
First step, a simple use of `sapply` "a user-friendly version and wrapper of lapply by default returning a vector, matrix", if `simplify = TRUE`, the default.

```
sapply(list.x, function(x) any(x > 3))
#      Foo    Foobar Foobarred 
#    FALSE      TRUE      TRUE
```

Step two. Since it also returns the `names`, I tried to see if `which` would keep them.

```
which(sapply(list.x, function(x) any(x > 3)))
#   Foobar Foobarred 
#        2         3
```

It does, so step three, wrap `names` around it.

```
names(which(sapply(list.x, function(x) any(x > 3))))
#[1] "Foobar"    "Foobarred"
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. The which call was the key I was missing. Thank you.

Comment: Or `names(list.x)[sapply(list.x, function(x) all(x > 3))]`

Comment: @RichScriven Right, I had thought of that and it now seems simpler but when I wrote it not so much so I opted for the solution in the answer.

Comment: @RichScriven Just realized that mine is one character shorter. Were this code golf and I would have won by 1 byte. (But conceptually yours is still simpler.)